# Should I be disposing EF4.0 ObjectContexts?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I've got a simple `UnitOfWork` pattern going with Entity Framework 4, like so:

```
public class UnitOfWork
{
    private readonly myEntities _context;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _context = new myEntities();
    }

    public myEntities Context { get { return _context; } }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Finish()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

My question is this: do I need that `Finish` method? Do I need to explicitly call `Dispose` on my `ObjectContext`-derived entity object, or should I just let the garbage collector take care of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the EF context is disposable and at its core represents a database connection yes, you should `Dispose()` it.

To make it a little easier on the consumers of your `UnitOfWork` class, I would make it implement `IDisposable` as well as opposed to providing a `Finish()` method. That way it can be used in a `using` block.

Comment: That's what I thought, makes sense - just wanted to verify! Thanks!